# Control sound permissions, revoke access to audio

Tags: sound, permissions

I would like to control permissions to use sound card. There are devices "/dev/snd/*", the owner is "root", group is "audio", permissions "660". So, I would expect only users in "audio" group could use sound card, however it doesn't work. I have a user "u1" which is not in group "audio", however he has access! I've found out that the access is controlled with ACL, so `getfacl` shows the following:

```
# file: timer
# owner: root
# group: audio
# flags: --t
user::rw-
user:u1:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

The line "user:u1:rw-" magically appears again even if I remove it with `setfacl`.

For me it looks like that there is a root-owned process which automatically adds permissions to any user ignoring "audio" group membership.

Why is the access granted? How to revoke access to sound card for a user?

Comment: Does the same happens with 13.10 or 14.04?

Comment: @Braiam I have 13.04 (why have you deleted the tag??), I don't have other versions around, but maybe I'll try to update to 13.10 and check if it helps, but it would take some time to upgrade.

Comment: Because 13.04 is EOL and is not longer supported. This issue may very well be fixed in later releases without intervention of your part.

Comment: You may be able to get around this by having a different user take ownership, but I see a problem as the system is going to be in control of this, as it is a device. You may have to remove access, versus denying access. I am not sure how helpful this is...

Comment: I suggest you check /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistant-alsa-rules, 78-soundcard.rules and so on.

Comment: it's by systemd, which installs [/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/login/71-seat.rules.in) which tags the sound devices with "seat". Then all devices tagged with "seat" have their ACLs adjusted automatically by systemd's "logind" service upon console switch (login/logind-acl.c and login/logind-seat.c). Removing the rules might help.

Answer (score 0):

**Check System**
To enable ACL, the filesystem must be mounted with the acl option.
It is very likely that the ACL option is already active as default mount option of your filesystem.
 Check typing (replace sdXY with correct partition):

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdXY | grep "Default mount options"
```

the output should be something like:

```
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
```

also check that the default mount option is not overridden, in such case you will see `noacl` in `/proc/mounts` in the relevant line. Type:

```
sudo cat /proc/mounts | grep noacl
```

If you need, you can set the default mount options of a filesystem using the tune2fs -o option partition command, for example:

```
 tune2fs -o acl /dev/sdXY
```

**Using ACL:**

to modify ACL use `setfacl`:

```
setfacl -m "u:username:permissions
```

or

```
setfacl -m "u:uid:permissions
```

for example, to revoke access to sound card for a user, type:

```
setfacl -m "u:u1:---" /dev/snd/controlC0
```

You can easily try if it works, putting playing an audio track and then executing the command: if the sound is interrupted, the command has been executed

You can also check if the permissions have been changed with:

```
getfacl /dev/snd/controlC0 ( Control Interface /dev/snd/controlCX )
```

Refer to manual `man acl` and  `man setfacl` for more options.

Comment: Yes, I've tried setfacl, it works, permissions are revoked, but suddenly after some time (cannot figure out exact moment when) permissions `user:u1:rw-` are changed somehow magically back and sound card works for user the again.

Answer (score 0):

The ACL for sound devices (and other "seat" devices) is controlled by the seat management service. For Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) and older this was done by the ConsoleKit service. For later versions this is replaced with systemd-logind. [This Ubuntu knowledge base article explains the reasoning](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup).

Technically you can remove devices from the seat definition, by either changing udev rules (remove the "`seat`" from devices) or by removing them from the seat manager device database using the D-Bus API (all these is from systemd-logind - I have no idea how this relates to ConsoleKit), but I can't think of a way to prevent just one specific logged in local user from gaining access to devices, while other local logged in user do get access to devices.